# Randomly Keep X Percent of Dictionary

Tags: python, django

I'm struggling with this one.

I need to randomly keep X percent of a dictionary for some analysis I'm doing.

A user would input a percentage of the data they would like to keep.
Example values: 10, 50, 70, 100

So when a user enters 30, how would I go about keeping 30 of every 100th element randomly?

I tried the below but it's not working because I need a dictionary back.  Suggestions?

```
images = {}
for vote in votes_selected:
    images[int(vote['id_left'])] = 1
    images[int(vote['id_right'])] = 1
selected_images = random.sample(images, int(len(images) * 50/100))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If ordering doesn't matter...

```
import random
random.sample(votes_selected, int(len(votes_selected) * DATA_PERCENTAGE / 100))
```

---

P.S. If votes_selected is actually a dict, then you can do this:

```
dict(random.sample(votes_selected.iteritems(), int(len(votes_selected) * DATA_PERCENTAGE / 100)))
```

Comment: I made a mistake.  It's not a list, it's a dictionary and I'm using it as a hash table.  Your code is returning a list as expected, but I need to return a dictionary so I can use it as a lookup after the random sampling has finished.

Comment: This solution returns an array of keys if `votes_selected` is a dict.